# Database Process vs. Manual Process

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, process

I'm currently studying databases and I am curious which is more expensive:

1. Processing data using sone's database commands (Ex. MongoDB's aggregate) or
2. Fetch from the database then process it manually.

For example, Averaging two data columns GradeA and GradeB.

1. Using the MongoDB process, it will just use `$avg` aggregation.
2. Meanwhile, processing it manually, will take loops and other programming constructs.

Which of the two is more expensive and will take the longer process? Is there any instances that manual process is good to be used?

**Example use case:**

I am fetching here two different collections. Do you think there's any way to simplify this code using MongoDB aggregate?

[image]

Comment: Measuring is the only way to know. Though in general what is going to be faster - code you just wrote or code that’s been written and optimized for a large audience by multiple developers?

Comment: That really depends on what you consider "expense".  Ex. if you measure expense in database server cycles, it is probably always cheaper to offload work to somewhere else.